# Counting number of times an int occurs in an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, int

I'm trying to count the number of occurences of `int`s, one to six inclusive, in an array of size 6. I want to return an array with the number of times an int appears in each index, but with one at index zero. 
**Example:**

**Input**: `[3,2,1,4,5,1,3]` 
**Expected output**: `[2,1,2,1,1,0]`.

**Problem:**
It outputs `[1,1,3,0,1,0]` with the code excerpt below. How can I fix this? I can't find where I'm going wrong.

```
public static int arrayCount(int[] array, int item) {
    int amt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == item) {
            amt++;
        }
    }
    return amt;
}

public int[] countNumOfEachScore(){
    int[] scores = new int[6];
    int[] counts = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        scores[i] = dice[i].getValue();
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        counts[j] = arrayCount(scores, j+1);
    }
    return counts;
}
```

dice[] is just an array of Die objects, which have a method getValue() which returns an int between 1 and 6, inclusive. counts[] is the int array with the wrong contents.

Comment: Why don't you use Collections.frequency() to get the count for each array elements

Comment: Your idea is very slow... @mhasan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be faster to write another code instead of debugging yours.

```
public static int[] count(int[] array) {
    int[] result = new int[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        try{
            result[array[i]-1]++;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The numbers must be between 1 and 6. Was " + String.valueOf(array[i]));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above will result in an array of 6 `int`s. `i`th number in the result array will store the number of occurences of `i+1`.

**PoC for the OP**
[image]

Comment: It still seems to be off. With input values of [1,2,4,4,3,5] it gave me [0,1,3,3,4,4], which isn't right.

Comment: It returns [1,1,1,2,1,0] on my machine. On my `Java Virtual Machine`.

Comment: @arnbobo can you show me more of your code? I'll try to help. If it started working, feel free to mark it as a solution.

Comment: @arnbobo you're welcome. I'll be happy to solve your problems in the future. Feel free to call me in comment.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static void main(String [] args){
        int []ar=new int[]{3,2,1,4,5,1,3};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(counter(ar)));

    }


public static int[] counter(int []ar){
        int []result=new int [6];
        for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
            int c=0;
            for(int j=0;j<ar.length;j++){
                if(j<i && ar[i]==ar[j])
                    break;
                if(ar[i]==ar[j])
                    c++;
                if(j==ar.length-1){
                    result[i]=c;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Check  your required input outputs, please.